# Invalid entry size error when using custom firefox profile with selenium-standalone-server

Tags: c#, firefox, webdriver

I am attempting to launch a remotewebdriver test on a client using a custom firefox profile stored locally. I'm not setting up a grid, I'm just trying to communicate with a client with selenium-standalone-server running.

The following snippet is how I'm initializing WebDriver.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("path_of_profile");
profile.AcceptUntrstedCertificates = false;
caps.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile.ToBase64String());
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://remoteClientIP:4444/wd/hub"), caps);
```

When I start the test, I get the following error:
invalid entry size (expected 10485760 but got 10289152 bytes)

with the following stack trace:
``` at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(DriverCommand driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary``2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) ```

Answer (score 2):

If your using RemoteWebDriver you need to set the browser and version so Selenium RC will know what browser to use to load.
Try adding this to your code:

```
    caps = new DesiredCapabilities(browserName, browserVersion, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
    caps.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile.ToBase64String());
```